# Regexp string JS

Tags: javascript, regexp-replace

didn't work with regexp previously, and now I need to get some part of string.

```
var str1 = "Wi-Fi: 6.3 ounces (180 grams); Wi-Fi + 3G: 6.6 oz (188 g)Actual size and weight may vary by configuration and manufacturing process";
```

I need get from this string only this digital from scope - 180 (here can be diferent digitals, and string can have other gext, but always should take digital from the scopes).

Here's my code:

```
var weight = $(data, "body").find("td:contains('Weight')").siblings().text();
        var regexp =  /\b(\d*\.?\d?)\sounces/im;
        var found = weight.replace(regexp, "");
        if (weight && weight != "") {
            return found;
        }
```

How to realize it? I saw some examples, but all the time in result have not what I want.

Thanks

Comment: If you have problems with a given piece of code you need to post it here. Otherwise it's nothing but a "do it for me" request, which is beyond the scope of the site.

Comment: ok, edited, there's nothing special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, work with next code:

```
var weight = $(data, "body").find("td:contains('Weight')").siblings().text();

var regexp =  /\b(\d*\.?\d?)\sounces/im;
var found = weight.match(regexp);
if (weight && weight != "") {
    return found[0];
}
```